# How to use Python to create a custom read data source for Apache Spark 3?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a lot of TDMS files produced by National Instruments's LabVIEW which saved in S3. I am hoping to create a custom read data source for Apache Spark 3, then later I can read by something like this

```scala
val df = spark.readStream
  .format("tdms")
  .option("limit", "10000")
```

Right now there is no Java or Scala library to read TDMS, but there is a good Python library [npTDMS](https://github.com/adamreeve/npTDMS) which can read TDMS files. I hope to leverage of it.

I know I can build a custom read data source for Spark in Java or Scala.

I am wondering is it possible to use Python to create a custom read data source? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple and direct way to do this currently. Spark SQL doesn't provide any way to implement Data Source (*connector*) in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to use `binary` or `text` or other built-in formats to load the TDMS files (that would preserve TDMS structure). That'd be a dataset loading step.

Next, you'd convert the dataset to proper TDMS format using custom python UDFs (that could also be registered to be available to SQL).